# Unix grep multiple character search

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I'm working on a problem in unix bash where it wants me to get an input from the user and then find if the input is valid (i.e. contains only A-Z a-z and the _ underscore character) and reject anything with a character other than those. For example Space_oddity would be valid while Space_oddity132 would be invalid.  I'm having trouble figuring out what the syntax of the grep command would be

```
if        $1 | grep '[A-Za-z_]'
echo "name is valid"
else
echo "name is not valid"
fi
```

I think I'm supposed to be using {m,} in the grep command but I'm not able to get the correct syntax despite looking at the list of regex commands.  Can anybody help me get the correct syntax or post something that is more helpful in understanding the syntax then what I have found so far?

Comment: It's not the command but the regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Portable Method

The `case` statement can accomplish this task and it is POSIX and consequently has the advantage of being portable:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    *[^[:alpha:]_]* )
        echo "name is not valid" ;;
    *)
        echo "name is valid" ;;
esac
```

This works because, if `$1` contains any unallowed character, that character will match `[^[:alpha:]_]` and the `not valid` message will be displayed.

#### Bash-Only Method 1

Using similar logic but using bash's `[[...]]` test command:

```
if [[ $1 = *[^[:alpha:]_]* ]]
then
    echo "name is not valid"
else
    echo "name is valid"
fi
```

#### Bash-Only Method 2

Alternatively, as suggested by [Benjamin W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w), we can do a substitution to remove all valid characters and then test if the resulting string is empty or not:

```
if [[ ${1//[[:alpha:]_]} ]]
then
    echo "Name is not valid"
else
    echo "Name is valid"
fi
```

Comment: Or (bit too similar for a separate answer): `if [[ ${1//[[:alpha:]_]} ]]; then` not valid.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Very good.  Answer updated to include your suggested approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) instead of `case`, make sure that you provide the string as an input to `grep`, and fix the regular expression:

```
if echo "$1" | grep -E -q '^[_[:space:]]+$'
then echo "Name is valid [$1]"
else echo "Name is invalid [$1]"
fi
```

The `-E` option enables extended regular expressions (`egrep` mode).  That's needed because of the `+`; alternatively, omit the `-E` and use `'^[_[:space:]][_[:space:]]*$'` as the regex instead. Both notations insist on at least one character between the start and end. The `[:space:]` notation is standard POSIX.  The `-q` option suppresses all normal output; it tells you whether the pattern was found (exit status 0, success) or not (exit status not 0).  The messages print the name that was validated too; it helps during debugging in particular (and is often helpful even after that).

Note that I use `echo "$1"` to avoid problems with spaces etc.  It isn't crucial here, but it is generally safest to enclose `$variable` notation in double quotes.  Note that there are times when that is not the correct way to use a variable, but it is very often the best way to do it.